# Can compiler allocates a memory on heap for a object

Tags: objective-c

Everybody say that in objective c ,all objects are store in heap.

Who is responsible to store the objects in heap ,Is it compiler?

NSString *myName=@"xyz";

In above line of code, object created at compile time.why?
Does @"xyz" stored in heap or stack?

Answer (score 1):

Static data (data that is defined at compile time) is stored in the binary file (executable, library, or framework). When that binary is loaded, the static data is loaded into memory along with it. It's not in the heap or the stack.

That includes Objective-C string literals such as `@"xyz"`.

Comment: Is there any way to store string literals in the heap? That way you can deallocate it when no longer needed. If string literals were always stored in static memory, then it would be a waste of space if you only use that string for a split second.

Comment: You cannot deallocate compile-time string literals. If you want something like that, put your strings in a data file that you load at runtime.